# Javascript compare 2 arrays of objects find matching values and make change

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var nickNames = [
  {
    nickName:"Dad",
    emailAddress:"dad@dad.com",
  },
  {
    nickName:"Mom",
    emailAddress:"mom@mom.com",
  },
  {
    nickName:"BFF",
    emailAddress:"bff@bff.com",
  }
]

var emails = [
  {
    from:"Dad Dadson <dad@dad.com>"
  },
  {
    from:"Mom Dadson <mom@mom.com>"
  },
  {
    from:"Brother Dadson <bro@bro.com>"
  }
]

for (var i=0; i < emails.length; i++) {
  emails[i].from.replace(/ *\<[^)]*\> */g, "")
}

for (var i=0; i < emails.length; i++) {
  if (emails.find(email => email.from) === nickNames.find(nick => nick.emailAddress)) {
    emails[i].nickName = nick.nickName
  }
}
```

Trying to accomplish 2 things:

1. Compare both arrays and see if there are any matches between:

```
nickNames.emailAddress
```

and

```
emails.from
```

The regex expression to isolate the email address works in a separate area of my code, but isn't accomplishing it here.

2. If there is a match, create a new key value pair in the matching emails array element, with the corresponding nickname.

Desired result:

```
emails = [
  {
    from:"dad@dad.com",
    nickName: "Dad"
  },
  {
    from:"mom@mom.com",
    nickName: "Mom"
  },
  {
    from:"bro@bro.com"
  }
]
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: People might have same nick names, so why don`t you just compare nickNames.emailAddress and emails.emailAddress and if they match add new key-value pair to emails element.

Comment: I apologize, I entered in the data wrong initially.  emails array does not have an emailAddress key.  I updated the question.

Comment: Is your regex supposed to extract the email within ```from```? And then if match with ```emailAddress``` you add to an array?

Comment: Provide the expected output after running the program with the 2 arrays you have, please.

Comment: @Inogueir  Yes.  If there is a match, I want to add a new key value pair to the matching element in the `emails` array: `nickName: "nickname"`  Thanks!

Comment: @Inogueir - I added the expected result to the question.  Thank you

Comment: Hello oakmaxluca! There're several solutions now, did any of them help you? If the answer is 'yes' then choose the best one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your regex is removing the email address from the `from` property, rather than preserving it. Here's a sample with a different regex that pulls out the email during comparison and ignores the rest.

```js
const nickNames = [
  {
nickName:"Dad",
emailAddress:"dad@dad.com",
  },
  {
nickName:"Mom",
emailAddress:"mom@mom.com",
  },
  {
nickName:"BFF",
emailAddress:"bff@bff.com",
  }
]

let emails = [
  {
from:"Dad Dadson <dad@dad.com>"
  },
  {
from:"Mom Dadson <mom@mom.com>"
  },
  {
from:"Brother Dadson <bro@bro.com>"
  }
]

emails.forEach(email => {
  const match = nickNames.find(nickName => nickName.emailAddress === email.from.replace(/^(.* )<(.+)>$/, "$2"));
  if (match) {
email.nickName = match.nickName;
  }
});
console.log(emails);
```

Comment: I'm only using a regex here because that's what the question proposed. This problem would be more efficiently solved by replacing the regex replace comparison with `email.from.includes('<' + nickName.emailAddress + '>')`, similar to the suggestion by @manaschopra98.

Answer (score 0):

The desired output can be obtained even without regex-

```
var nickNames = [
  {
nickName:"Dad",
emailAddress:"dad@dad.com",
  },
  {
nickName:"Mom",
emailAddress:"mom@mom.com",
  },
  {
nickName:"BFF",
emailAddress:"bff@bff.com",
  }
]

var emails = [
  {
from:"Dad Dadson <dad@dad.com>"
  },
  {
from:"Mom Dadson <mom@mom.com>"
  },
  {
from:"Brother Dadson <bro@bro.com>"
  }
]

nickNames.forEach(item=>{
    emails.forEach((entry)=>{
        if(entry.from.includes(item.emailAddress))
        {
            entry.nickname = item.nickName;
        }
    });
});

console.log(emails);
```

Comment: Direct comparison like that will not work since `emails.from` is not normalized - it contains names and `<>`, whereas nickNames.emailAddress is normalized.

Comment: .includes function matches the part of the string and not just the complete string, so it will work in your case. 
Example : 
var s = "Dad Dadson <dad@dad.com>"; 
s.includes("dad@dad.com");  will return true.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. When I saw .includes I was thinking it was `Array.prototype.includes`. I see now that you have a nested array and are using `String.prototype.includes`. It works, but will result in false positivies.

Comment: Could you please give an example for false positive in this case? @hemp

Comment: Sure. If `item.emailAddress` is "me@you.com" it will match "writetome@you.com" in `entry.from`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mapEmailsToNickNames(emails, nickNames) {

  // With this function we'll create
  // a mapping from emailAddress to nickName
  const addKeyValue = (map, { nickName, emailAddress }) => {
    map.set(emailAddress, nickName);
    return map;
  };

  // Learn about Array#reduce it's super useful
  const mapEmailsToNickNames = nickNames.reduce(addKeyValue, new Map());

  // This regex will be used to extract
  // an email from <bro@bro.com> like strings
  const regexpEmail = new RegExp(/\<(.*)\>$/);
  
  // Learn about Array#map function.
  // It's highly useful
  // basically it allows you to run a function
  // on each element of an array and replace the original element
  // with a function output
  return emails.map(({ from }) => {
    // extract email from a pattern <email>
    const email = from.match(regexpEmail)[1];

    // check to see if an email has a nickName
    const nickName = mapEmailsToNickNames.get(email);
    if (nickName) {
      return { email, nickName };
    } else {
      return { email };
    }
  });
}

const result = mapEmailsToNickNames(emails, nickNames);
console.log(result);
```

It's a more functional solution, and it should perform better on larger datasets.

By the way, maybe your choice of data structures isn't the best here, try looking into using sets, maps, and object, you may find them useful when you need to search for an item.

Comment: While it doesn't appear to hurt anything, I believe `<` and `>` in your regex don't need to be escaped?